# Check if a jar directory contains a folder

Tags: java, file, jar, path

hey there i want to check that from where my jar is running (path of jar) that directory contains a certain folder i am trying like:

```
 try{
    File fofjar=new File((PackLoader.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()));

    File f=new File(fofjar.toString()+"\\myfol");
    System.out.println(f.toPath());
    if (Files.exists(f.toPath())) {
       System.out.printlin("folder is there!")

    }
    else{
        throw new Exception("\n"+f.toPath());
    }

}catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "directory does not exist\n" + e + "\nClass:Pack Loader", "Not Found Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

The problem is that the jar directory returned is fine for me but there is some problem when a directory myfol exists inside my jar directory location it stills throws an exception can somebody tell me what is the problem I am new to this work thanks

Comment: A "jar directory", that is, a directory within a jar?

Comment: a folder that contains my jar (checking if the folder that contains my jar is having myfol or not)

Comment: Ah, OK, this was not clear. You should use a `Path` directly, then, and use `.resolveSibling()`

Comment: not getting your comment @fge

Comment: where is resolveSibling() method lols

Comment: It is a method of `Path`. But given what you want to do you don't need it, actually; you need `.resolve()`. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
final Path dir = Paths.get(PackLoader.class.getProtectionDomain()
    .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());

return Files.isDirectory(dir.resolve("myfol"));
```

Comment: What error? You say in your question that an exception is thrown but you don't actually show it